# Google map GMSMarker warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have integrated google map SDK in my iOS app. It gives following warning in debug area.

**Marker set as selectedMarker while not belonging to this map. Ignoring.**

If any one have idea then please share it.

Comment: I have added GMSMapView and multiple GMSMarker nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the steps listed in Google Developers Guide?: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start. I guess i might have missed out somewhere in adding the frameworks listed.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create a GMSMarker, you'll want to set its map property. Check out Google's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_overlay#adf140b1a471eec414d7bd3917beb3ef0). Swift example below, but the `.map` call is the same in Objective-C.

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10, longitude: 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```

Line 4 is the key here. Failing to do that will throw the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that you forget to set `marker.map = mapView`,
the second and the most common reason for whom interacting with markers is  that you return 'false' in
`mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool`
, the documentation said:

> return YES if this delegate handled the tap event, which prevents the
> map from performing its default selection behavior, and NO if the
> map should continue with its default selection behavior.